# wirewound adjustable resistor. Something I missed?

Tags: led, resistors, resistance, voltage-measurement

I am by no means an expert on electronics, but I thought that I had a fairly good grasp of the basics. That is, until 10 minutes ago.

1 picture ~ 1000 words, so here is what I have:
[image: my resistor from ebay and some wires.]

The yellow wire is +12VDC and the black is ground.
From one end to the other, the resistor is 1KOhm, I have measured and confirmed that.
But for some reason, if I place the multimeters positive probe on one end of the resistor (not the one where the yellow wire attaches) and the negative to the black wire going back into the PSU, I get 12.04V which is exactly the same as when just placing the probe directly on the yellow wire.

How come there is no voltage drop even though the current is going through a 1KOhm resistor?

The resistor is rated for 100W (dunno if that is important).
All I want to do is drive 2 10W LED's that are rated for 9v-11v.

What am I doing wrong? What have I not understood correctly here? Did a bit of googling but with little luck.

Many thanks for any help :)

Comment: Its worth noting that you'll probably burn out your LEDs trying to use a resistor like this.  High-power devices like very specific inputs.

Comment: @insta is it because it is too hard to hit the correct voltage? I have of course measured it to be 10V before connecting the LED. Or is it something else?

Comment: LEDs I believe exhibit a positive temperature coefficient.  Ergo, as they heat up, they conduct more.  You need an active driver to continuously monitor and adjust the current powering the LED ... or run them far below their 10W threshold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should place the supply voltage across the resistor, which means that the black wire has to be connected to the other end of the rheostat (or variable resistor).

Then, if you want the intermediate value, you have to connect the negative probe (black) of the instrument to the negative cable of the supply and the positive probe to the moving cursor, that causes the voltage division.

Moving the cursor will cause a variation in the voltage due to the different ratio of the resistors.

[Here](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/#%24+1+5.0E-6+10.20027730826997+50+5.0+43%0Av+192+368+192+96+0+0+40.0+12.0+0.0+0.0+0.5%0A174+336+160+336+352+0+1000.0+0.0050+Resistance%0Aw+192+368+336+368+0%0Aw+336+352+336+368+0%0Aw+336+160+336+96+0%0Aw+192+96+336+96+0%0AO+352+256+464+256+0%0Aw+336+368+352+368+0%0Ar+384+256+384+368+0+1000000.0%0Aw+384+368+352+368+0%0Aw+384+256+352+256+0%0A) is a simulation of what you should achieve (just for completeness I've added the internal resistance of the voltmeter)

Answer (score 7):

What you got was exactly as expected.  Think about it.  Drawing out the schematic helps:

[image]

R1 (your adjustable resistor end to end) and Rm (the resistance of the voltmeter) form a voltage divider.  The voltage accross Rm is the input voltage times Rm/(R1 + Rm).  I'll let you work that out.

I assumed 10 MΩ for the voltmeter resistance, which is probably about right if you have a modern electronic meter.  If this is a old analog meter then it could be less, maybe as low a 1 MΩ.  Either way though, it won't change the above answer much.

Comment: It works properly, as you say, but not exactly "as expected", because I think that the OP was expecting something else :)

Comment: @clabacchio: It worked exactly as anyone with a good grasp of the basics should have expected.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of putting it: there is (essentially) no current through the resistor so there is no volt drop along it. (Within measurement limit of your meter).